# Using Conditional Formatting in Excel to only format the cell if 2 conditions are met

Tags: excel, excel-formula, conditional-formatting

After a bit of consternation I managed to come up with a pretty simple solution to highlight cells in a range if a cell in a different range has the same value:

```
=MATCH(RC,'Interactive Calendar'!C2,0)>0
```

What I'd like to do next, and I'm having some difficulty figuring it out, is to check if `C3` in the Interactive Calendar sheet has a specific value based around location.

So `IF =MATCH(RC,'Interactive Calendar'!C2,0)>0 AND` the corresponding cell in `'Interactive Calendar'!C3="Brisbane"`, then format the cell. There are three locations, Melbourne, Brisbane and Sydney so the plan was to have 3 different formatting rules across the same area.

Comment: Are you using R1C1 as your setup?  Are your columns Numbers or Letters?

Comment: @Scott Craner I'm using R1C1 as that was the simplest way to use the Active Cell as part of the formula.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use:

```
=AND(ISNUMBER(MATCH(RC,'Interactive Calendar'!C2,0)),INDEX('Interactive Calendar'!C3,MATCH(RC,'Interactive Calendar'!C2,0))='Brisbane")
```

Comment: Thanks Scott - didn't quite get the required result though. It is matching dates and not numbers though if that affects the formula?

Comment: Nothing happened. It's not applying the formatting to the cell with the second condition.

Comment: If that does not work, make sure your dates are: 1. True dates and not text. 2. That they do not include a time portion to the data that is being masked by the format.

Comment: Fantastic, that appears to have worked. I'll run a few more tests and then give it the tick.